# How can I get the length of my filtered ngRepeat array in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement pagination in my angular app. I have an array of 1000+ books, and I'd like my `currentPage / totalPages` vars to update based on my `filter`ed `ngRepeat`.

Here's my current Angular code:

```
function Books($scope, $http, $rootScope){
    $scope.books = [1000+ books];
    $scope.filteredbooks = [];

    $scope.numberOfPages = function(){
        return Math.ceil($scope.filteredbooks.length / $scope.pageSize);
    }
}
```

My next / prev buttons:

```
<button ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage-1">
     Previous
</button>
{{currentPage+1}}/{{numberOfPages()}}
<button ng-disabled="currentPage >= data.length/pageSize - 1" 
        ng-click="currentPage=currentPage+1">
     Next
</button>
```

Here's my ngRepeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="book in (filteredbooks = books | filter: search) | 
               orderBy: 'title' | startFrom: currentPage * pageSize | 
               limitTo: pageSize">
     {{book.title}}
</tr>
```

My problem is that `filteredbooks` in my `ngRepeat` isn't setting my `$scope.filteredbooks`, so my length for total pages isn't updating. Is there a way to do this?

Also is there an event or directive that I can hook into to set my `$scope.currentPage` to 0 when the search term is changed?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here's a fiddle of the go-to example with a search box: http://jsfiddle.net/4LRbN/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function to tell the page where to start from.

### DEMO

In Angular you already have a built-in function `limitTo` so we're just adding the `startFrom` function so it can track it's location the results.

`{{(data.length}}` will give you the total number of results.
`{{(data|filter:searchterm).length}}` will give you the number of filtered results.

Updated **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4LRbN/1/)**.

I would also recommend looking at the example fiddles on Angular's wiki [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/JsFiddle-Examples).

Comment: That's the exact fiddle I followed along with. It's missing `filter`ing, with the `total-pages` updated when a new search-term is typed. Do you know how to get the length of the resulting filtered array?

Comment: @Prodikl - See the `numberOfReults()` function I added to the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/2ZzZB/926/.

Comment: Thank you. Could you check out this fiddle?:http://jsfiddle.net/4LRbN/ (I added filtering, and I'm having trouble with `numberOfResults` reflecting the filtered array)

Comment: @Prodikl - The problem is all of this is 'filtering' data that's already been loaded in the browser.

Comment: @Prodikl - I've updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4LRbN/1/). Using `{{(data|filter:searchterm).length}}` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll accept your answer! Would there be a way to write that in my JS code? `$scope.pagesTotal = function(){ return Math.ceil(($scope.data|filter:$scope.searchterm).length / $scope.pageSize);}` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Prodikl - It cannot be in the JS code _because_ it is filtering *all* of the data that has already been loaded on the page by the JS code.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the responses and all the help

Answer (score 1):

Here is more samples for that

[Pagination on a list using ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581209/angularjs-pagination-on-a-list-using-ng-repeater)

or take a look this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19410927/2218635

Result like

[image]

see : [How to achieve pagination/table layout with Angular.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409492/how-to-achieve-pagination-table-layout-with-angular-js)

Comment: Thank you very much for the link, I was looking through that example, but finding the meat and potatoes of it was pretty tough.