# Pagination with textbox in between next and prev go to page number in Angular js table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want angular js pagination with next prev button and in between i need a textbox to go direct to any page number in angular js table
please help me

Answer (score 0):

This post will give you a head start for your approach.

[How to achieve pagination/table layout with Angular.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409492/how-to-achieve-pagination-table-layout-with-angular-js)

Regarding textbox based page change, you will have to bind the current page number to the text box.

**Edit :**

This is a js fiddle from the above post.

http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/1754/

Add this line before the Next Prev buttons:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="currentPageManual"/>
```

& In the controller ,
Add these lines :

```
$scope.currentPageManual = 1;


$scope.$watch("currentPage", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.currentPageManual = newValue+1;
    });


    $scope.$watch("currentPageManual", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.currentPage = newValue-1;
    });
```

I am sure there are elegant ways of doing this..

Comment: Thanks for the comment but i have seen this link. Can you please give me example of textbox binding to a page.