# dynamic pagination in angular

Tags: html, angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I built an angular app that have table with data. I show it with the pagination concept, 3 lines in a page, and it works, but when I add new data(user) to the table, it doesn't adds page in the pagination bar.

the angular code:

```
app = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $modal, $log ) {
    $scope.Users = [{
        'userN': 'Ariel1',
        'PassW': 'Aa123456',
        'Name': 'Ariel',
        'LastName': 'Livshits'
    }, {
        'userN': 'Ariel2',
        'PassW': 'Aa123456',
        'Name': 'Ariel',
        'LastName': 'Livshits'
    }, {
        'userN': 'Ariel3',
        'PassW': 'Aa123456',
        'Name': 'Ariel',
        'LastName': 'Livshits'
    }, {
        'userN': 'Ariel4',
        'PassW': 'Aa123456',
        'Name': 'Ariel',
        'LastName': 'Livshits'
    }, {
        'userN': 'Ariel5',
        'PassW': 'Aa123456',
        'Name': 'Ariel',
        'LastName': 'Livshits'
    }, {
        'userN': 'Ariel6',
        'PassW': 'Aa123456',
        'Name': 'Ariel',
        'LastName': 'Livshits'
    }, {
        'userN': 'Ariel6',
        'PassW': 'Aa123456',
        'Name': 'Ariel',
        'LastName': 'Livshits'
    }, {
        'userN': 'Ariel6',
        'PassW': 'Aa123456',
        'Name': 'Ariel',
        'LastName': 'Livshits'
    }];

    $scope.User = {
        'username': '',
        'Password': '',
        'connected': false
    };


    $scope.viewby = 3;
    $scope.totalItems = $scope.Users.length;
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.itemsPerPage = $scope.viewby;
    $scope.maxSize = ($scope.Users.length / 3) + 1; //Number of pager buttons to show

    $scope.setPage = function (pageNo) {
        $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
    };

    $scope.pageChanged = function() {
        console.log('Page changed to: ' + $scope.currentPage);
    };

    $scope.setItemsPerPage = function(num) {
        $scope.itemsPerPage = num;
        $scope.currentPage = 1; //reset to first paghe
    };


    $scope.openR = function() {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'table.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
        });
        modalInstance.result.then(function(newUser) {
            $scope.Users.push(newUser);
        }, function() {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };
    $scope.openC = function() {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'connect.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
        });
        modalInstance.result.then(function(conUser) {
            $scope.User = conUser;
        }, function() {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };
});

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance) {
    $scope.okR = function() {
        $modalInstance.close({
            'userN': $scope.userN,
            'PassW': $scope.PassW,
            'Name': $scope.Name,
            'LastName': $scope.LastName
        });
    };

    $scope.okC = function() {
        $modalInstance.close({
            'username': $scope.username,
            'Password': $scope.password,
            'connected': true
        });
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

the html code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">

<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.3.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" >
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openR()"> add user </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openC()"> connect </button>
    <div class="btn btn-success" ng-show="User.connected">{{User.username}} is connected</div>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <th class="col-lg-3">Username</th>
        <th class="col-lg-3">Password</th>
        <th class="col-lg-3">First name</th>
        <th class="col-lg-3">Last name</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="User in Users.slice(((currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage), ((currentPage)*itemsPerPage))">
            <td class="col-lg-3">{{User.userN}}</td>
            <td class="col-lg-3">{{User.PassW}}</td>
            <td class="col-lg-3">{{User.Name}}</td>
            <td class="col-lg-3">{{User.LastName}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div >
        <pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()" class="pagination-sm" items-per-page="itemsPerPage"></pagination>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="table.html">
    <form ng-submit="okR()">
        <div class="modal-header" >
            <h3>users</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Username :</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Ariel73" ng-model="userN">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password :</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Aa123456" ng-model="PassW">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>First name :</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Ariel" ng-model="Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Last name :</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Livshits" ng-model="LastName">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="connect.html">
    <form ng-submit="okC()">
        <div class="modal-header" >
            <h3>users</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Username :</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Ariel73" ng-model="username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password :</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Aa123456" ng-model="password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409492/how-to-achieve-pagination-table-layout-with-angular-js for pagination

Comment: my pagination is working. the problem is when i add user to the table, it doesn't add new page in the pagination bar. this links don't have a solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is "pagination" your own directive?

The way angular works is it will run your "controller" code only once when the directive loads.

You can do one of two things. Add a "watch" in the "pagination" controller to update when one of your "scope variables" on the directive pagination updates. Or set up an event(broadcast or emit, and an on) that lets pagination know to update when users updates.

Here is a [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) to documentation of setting up a $watch variable.